# Regex expression to test strength of a password

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regex that should only match if the string contains minimum 10 to 16 characters with atleast, a number, a string, an uppercase, a lowercase character and a special character.

I think this string should pass this regexp test but  <strike>this is not working</strike>  : 
The String does not include the apostrpohes' or quotes.
String : 'asdf@A1234';

Regexp: `/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{10,16}$/;`
Can someone kindly suggest what I am missing?

```
function testpwd(pwd) {
                var re = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{10,16}$/;
             console.log(" Test Result is " + re.test(pwd) )
                return re.test(pwd);
            }
```

**Update**
Sorry for the red flag Guys. The code is working.  The error was somewhere else :). I am rephrasing the question so that It can be of some use for future visitors.

Comment: `(?=...)` means match this string if this pattern follows the match.

Comment: Yes, that string passes that regex

Comment: but it returns false in my js

Comment: downvoters .. kindly give me a moment while I post  my JS code..

Comment: Please clarify if the string is inclusive of the two `'`.

Comment: Kindly suggest an edit in JS.

Comment: No need to edit, [**it works**](https://jsfiddle.net/1xkbrgt3/2/).

Comment: Please refer to [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922/reference-password-validation/)

Answer (score 2):

It does appear to work, https://regex101.com/r/2u0jZ2/1

Without the quotes and semi colon though. If the quotes and semi colon are part of the string, then that's the reason the match isn't happening

Answer (score 0):

this is a strong regex accept 14  numbers and capital letter small leter all symbols in keyboard
start
/(?=[A-Za-z0-9@#$%^&+!?=*.()_-~/-]+$)^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[@#$^&+!=])(?=.{14,}).*$/
end